# How to handle screen rotation while using ZXingScannerView?

Tags: android, camera, qr-code, screen-orientation

I have an `Activity` for scanning QR code using `ZXingScannerView`.

In `OnCreate` method I generate view like this:

```
    mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this) {
            @Override
            protected IViewFinder createViewFinderView(Context context) {
                IViewFinder viewFinder = super.createViewFinderView(context);
                if (viewFinder instanceof ViewFinderView) {
                    ((ViewFinderView) viewFinder).setSquareViewFinder(true);
                }
                return viewFinder;
            }
        };
setContentView(mScannerView);
```

Then when screen is rotated, the layout is very bad like this image:
[image]

So in `OnConfigurationChanged` method I try to **stop the scanner** and **start it again**. Even I tried to **recreate the scanner**.

The layout now looks fine. But the QR scanner doesn't work. It doesn't recognize the QR code.

Please tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Its better to use `mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);` rather than start it again.

Comment: @Piyush **resume** and help to refresh the layout. But the scanner still doesn't recognize the QR code.

Answer (score 1):

In manifest file just add

```
 <activity
        android:name=".your class name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"            
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

You also add bellow code in manifest

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```